# Trying to sum compute my select statement

Tags: linq, lambda, sum

I want to rewrite this statement into a Linq statement with lambda.

```
var summe1 = (from l in db.Lg7s
    && new int[]{0,40}.Contains(l.REATE)
    && l.ANSWERING>0
    select (l.TALKINGTIME + l.ONHOLDTIME + l.ACTIONTIME + l.UPTIME)).Sum(i => i);
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
T4Number =  group
    .Where(lg => new int[]{38,40}.Contains(lg.CAUSE) && lg.ANSWERING>0)
    .Select(lg => new {DurationOfCallProcessing = lg.EN_ TALKINGTIME + lg.EN_ ONHOLDTIME + lg.EN_ ACTIONTIME + lg.UPTIME })
    .Sum()
```

But the ide said, that Sum isn´t valid.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "Sum" an anonymous type. I guess you want:

```
T4Number =  group
    .Where(lg => new int[]{38,40}.Contains(lg.CAUSE) && lg.ANSWERING>0)
    .Select(lg => new {DurationOfCallProcessing = lg.EN_ TALKINGTIME + lg.EN_ ONHOLDTIME + lg.EN_ ACTIONTIME + lg.UPTIME })
    .Sum(x => x.DurationOfCallProcessing);
```

But if you only want the sum there is no need to create the anonymos type at all:

```
T4Number =  group
    .Where(lg => new int[]{38,40}.Contains(lg.CAUSE) && lg.ANSWERING>0)
    .Sum(lg => lg.EN_ TALKINGTIME + lg.EN_ ONHOLDTIME + lg.EN_ ACTIONTIME + lg.UPTIME);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without the anonymous type:

```
var causes = new [] { 38, 40 };

T4Number =  group
    .Where(lg => causes.Contains(lg.CAUSE) && lg.ANSWERING>0)
    .Select(lg => lg.EN_ TALKINGTIME + lg.EN_ ONHOLDTIME + lg.EN_ ACTIONTIME + lg.UPTIME })
    .Sum()
```

This also improves the filter predicate by no longer `new`-ing the causes each time